# One-to-many dropdownlist suggestion

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having hard time trying to figure out which way to go.
Before i start, here some of the classes :

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }   
}

public class Category {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID {get;set;}

    public Category Parent{get;set;}

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

So, to create a new "Car", I simply need a page with a dropdown for all of the categories. To do that, I wrote a new class and passed it to "ActionResult Create"...

Here it is :

```
public class CarCreate
{
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            List<Category> list = new List<Category>();

            SystemContext sc = new SystemContext();

            list = sc.Categories.ToList();
            list.Insert(0, null);

            sc.Dispose();

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

And from the controller I passed it like this:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new CarCreate());
    }
```

And within the view, I created a dropdown for List in CarCreate class:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Car.Title)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Car.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Car.Category)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Car.Category, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID", "Title","Select"), new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

And when I check the Car.Category within the ActionResult that handles postback like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CarCreate emc)
    {
       Response.Write(emc.Car.Title);
        Response.Write(emc.Car.Category== null ? "null" : "notnull");
        return View(new CarCreate());
    }
```

I can get title. But category is always null.

What would I have to do to get category from postback?

Comment: I think Car.Category will always be null cause you have `CarCreate` as a parameter to the `Action`. I think what you need is adding a new property categoryID  in the Car Class which should be mapped with the selected dropdown value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DropDownListFor is mapped with a value wich is defined by the option selected in the select.
You try to set this value in a complex object.

I think you should have a things like

```
 public class Car
 {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }

    public virtual int CategoryID { get ; set;}

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

 }
```

And

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Car.Category)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Car.CategoryID, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID", "Title","Select"), new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because your Category is not instanciate. Try to add this in the Car constructor :

```
public class Car
{   
     public Car() 
     {
           this.Category = new Category();
     }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Try to instanciate Car in CreateCar's controller

Comment: Thanks for the advice.But int categoryID {get;set;} solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I would keep my viewmodels as lite as i can. Just keep the properties you really need in your view. Also i prefer to keep those as simple POCO's(not with data loading logic in that) so that i can use that in many places.

```
public class CreateCarVM
{
  [Required]
  public string Title { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Categories { set;get;}
  [Required]
  public int SelectedCategory { set;get;}
  public CreateCarVM()
  {
    Categories =new List<SelectListItem>();
  }
}
```

and in my create action method,

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new CreateCarVM();
  vm.Categories=GetCategories();
  return View(vm);
}
private List<SelectListItem> GetCategories()
{
  var list=new List<SelectListItem>();
  //2 items hard coded for demo. You may load it from db
  list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="Sedan"});
  list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="SUV"});
  return list;
}
```

and in your View which is strongly typed to the `CreateCarVM`

```
@model CreateCarVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Title)
 @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedCategory,Model.Categories,"Select")
 <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now when the form is posted, You can check the `SelectedCategory` property of the viewmodel

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateCarVM model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //check for model.SelectedCategory now
   // to do :Save and Redirect (PRG pattern)
  }
  model.Categories=GetCategories();
  return View(model);
}
```